# Prev and Next Buttons on PHP Calendar

Tags: php

```
href=\"index.php?month=". ($month - 1) . "&year=$year

href=\"index.php?month=" . ($month + 1) . "&year=$year\
```

The first link makes the calendar go back one month when clicked, and the second link makes the calendar go forward one month, the problem is if $month = 1 i.e. "Jan" then $month equals 0.

I'm trying to instead get 0 to be 1 and get $year to decrement by 1.

Any suggestions on the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: `if($month==0` ..... it seems rather simple, what have you tried?

Comment: Shouldn't it go to 12 in the previous year rather than 1?

Comment: Dagon, Thanks my second equals sign. *bangs head on wall

Answer (score 0):

Just use a ternary operator:

```
href=\"index.php?month=". ($month - 1 == 0?12:$month - 1) . "&year=$year
```

which basically means:

```
if($month - 1 == 0)
       echo 12;
    else
       echo $month - 1;
```

Same goes for next month:

```
    href=\"index.php?month=" . ($month + 1 == 13?0:$month + 1) . "&year=$year
```